# how to split file in arrays and find maximum value in each of them

Tags: arrays, awk, split, max

I have a file:

```
1   0.5
2   0.7
3   0.55
4   0.7
5   0.45
6   0.8
7   0.75
8   0.3
9   0.35
10  0.5
11  0.65
12  0.75
```

I want to split the file into 4 arrays ending on every next 3rd line and then to find the maximum value in the second column for every array. So this file the outcome would be the:

```
3     0.7
6     0.8
9     0.75
12    0.75
```

I have managed so far to split the file into several by

```
awk 'NR%3==1{x="L"++i;}{print > x}' filename
```

then to find the maximum in every file:

```
awk  'BEGIN{max=0}{if(($2)>max)  max=($2)}END {print $1,max}'
```

However, this creates additional files which is fine for this example but in reality the original file contains 65 million lines so I will be a bit overwhelmed by the amount of files and I am trying to avoid it by writing a short script which will combine both of the mentioned above.

I tried this one:

```
awk  'BEGIN {for (i=1; i<=12; i+=3) {max=0} {if(($2)>max)  max=($2)}}END {print $1,max}' Filename
```

but it produces something irrelevant.

So if you can help me out it will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You could go for something like this:

```
awk 'NR % 3 == 1 || $2 > max {max = $2} NR % 3 == 0 {print $1, max}' file
```

The value of `max` is always reset every three rows and updated if value of the second column is greater than it. At the end of every group of three, the first column and the max are printed.